# How to write a php function that the input is array and the function finds the lowest number

Tags: php, arrays, function

Hello how can i create a php function that the input is an array and the function finds the lowest number in the array.

Comment: function minarray ($massiv = []){
    foreach($massiv as $data) {
        min($data);
    }

}

minarray($array = [1,2]);

Comment: Why you dont use `min();` ?

Comment: Because i have to create a function like min. I cant use direct min();

Comment: This question looks like homework. You should hit the books and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function makes a few assumptions, such as the value being passed in is actually an array with some values in it. You could add some validation for that if you wished...

```
function findLowest($myArray)
{
    $currLowest=$myArray[0];
    foreach($myArray as $val)
    {
        if($val < $currLowest)
        {
            $currLowest=$val;
        }
    }
    return $currLowest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can be achieved using built in functions or custom functions

```
$numbers=array( 4 => 40, 3 => 30, 13 => 38 );
function getMin($source = array())
{
 //If you don't need your original index for the lowest value  
   sort($source);
 // after sort original index is lost.
   return $source[0]

 //OR

//If you need your original index for the lowest value  
   asort($source);
   foreach($source as $key => $value)
   {
       return $value; //ie return key or value that you need.
   }
}
```

Use any one logic from the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers=array( 4 => 40, 3 => 30, 13 => 38 );
function getMin($source = array())
{
 //If you don't need your original index for the lowest value  
   sort($source);
 // after sort original index is lost.
   return $source[0]

 //OR

//If you need your original index for the lowest value  
   asort($source);
   foreach($source as $key => $value)
   {
       return $value; //ie return key or value that you need.
   }
}
```

This helped me. :)